# Custom Attribute Not Firing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, authorize-attribute

I have a project with both MVC and Web API controllers in it. It uses Windows Auth. However I want to protect a particular Web API action with a custom attribute. I have created the following just to get the basic flow set up (ultimately it will check the users IP address):

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;

namespace UoB.People.UserInterface.Mvc.Filters
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class IPAuthorize : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
    {
        protected bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I have decorated my Web API action with a call to this attribute. Problem is, when I run my code locally, the attribute code is never hit. The action is. This particular action belongs to a controller which does not use Windows Auth.

Why is my attribute not being called? Does it need to be registered somewhere? Is there a conflict because my project contains both MVC and Web API controllers? Have I made a simple error somewhere?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured out my problem. I actually needed to override OnAuthorization and AuthorizeCore. The following example demonstrates this:

```
public class IPAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public string AuthorisedIPs { get; set; }

    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (AuthorizeCore((HttpContextBase)actionContext.Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]))
            return;

        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
    }

    protected bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        // Logic here.
    }
}
```

Hope this helps if anyone else is having trouble.

Answer (score 2):

You need to register your attribute in RegisterGlobalFilters in your FilterConfig.cs class.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, this will register the filter as global, i.e. call it for all requests.